# a problem about compactness and sequential compactness in metric space

Tags: metric-spaces, compactness

Consider a metric space $(\Bbb N, d)$ where $d(m,n) = \frac{\vert m-n \vert} {1+\vert m-n \vert}$.

Need to prove that any infinite subset $X \subset \Bbb Z$ is not compact and not sequentially compact.

(Have previously proven that every set in $(\Bbb N, d)$ defined above is open and closed, and that $(\Bbb N, d)$ is complete.)

I find the question a bit odd, as there are 2 spaces involved: $\Bbb N$ and $\Bbb Z$. So I just take it to mean "not compact and not sequentially compact" in $(\Bbb Z, d)$ rather than $(\Bbb N, d)$

So I suspect the trick for this question is that $\Bbb Z$ is topologically equivalent to $\Bbb N$ ("homeomorphism"?) and I need to consider infinite subsets $X' \subset \Bbb N$ and use my previous results about $(\Bbb N, d)$

Also, to answer this question, I suppose I just need to prove either X is not compact or not sequentially compact, since the 2 are equivalent for any metric space. I also think that (correct me if I'm wrong) in any metric space, a subset is compact iff it is closed and bounded. But I don't really know how to proceed. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly suspect that $\Bbb Z$ is simply a typo for $\Bbb N$, and that you’re actually to show that no infinite subset of $\Bbb N$ is compact or sequentially compact.

It is not in general true that in metric spaces the compact sets are precisely the closed and bounded sets. For example, the set $\Bbb Q\cap[0,1]$ is closed and bounded in the metric space $\Bbb Q$ with the usual Euclidean metric, but it is not compact. You should start with an arbitrary infinite $X\subseteq\Bbb N$ and show directly that it is neither compact nor sequentially compact.

- To show that $X$ is not compact, find an open cover of $X$ that has no finite subcover. HINT: You’ve already shown that $\{x\}$ is open for each $x\in\Bbb N$.
- To show that $X$ is not sequentially compact, find an infinite sequence in $X$ that has no convergent subsequence. HINT: Prove that any infinite sequence with no repeated terms has this property.

Comment: this actually brings me to another question I had: should I take "infinite subset X" as meaning a set with infinite number of elements with none repeating? because if X is bounded and contains element(s) that are repeated infinitely many times then surely every open cover has a finite subcover(?)

Comment: sorry i think i was confusing infinite sets with infinite sequences...

Comment: @Alex: Yes, you were. An infinite set by definition has infinitely many distinct elements; an infinite sequence has infinitely many terms, but they could all be the same point.

Answer (score 1):

The metric $d$ on $\mathbb N$ is equivalent topologically to the metric $|x-y|$ on $\mathbb N$. So, any set which is not compact in $\mathbb N$ with usual metric cannot be compact in this metric space also. Now any infinite set of $\mathbb N$ with usual metric is unbounded as $\mathbb N$ has no limit points. So, no infinite set in $\mathbb N$ with usual metric can be compact and hence no infinite set in $\mathbb N$ with $d$ metric can be compact.